# how to restore code version after wrong rebase?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

I did a rebase before pushing my local code commits.

I skipped rebase step and my code changes gone.

the issue is:
I had first commit -> some local commits -> rebase

I tried to restore by check with **git reglog** but my local changes are not there:

```
52f02f5 (HEAD -> ori-add-3dots-button) HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/ori-add-3dots-button
52f02f5 (HEAD -> ori-add-3dots-button) HEAD@{1}: rebase: initial commit
```

but between those two were some local commits.

Is there a way to restore those commits or this code in some way?

*I use VScode

thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of starting a rebase and not solving the merge conflicts? typo: it is `reflog`

Answer (score 0):

Check the older reflog entries (`HEAD@{2}` and below), the commit which contains the changes you are looking for should be there.